# S3 Presigned URL Issue - file upload successful, 200 statusCode but no response body

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This was working up until recently, I am not sure what has changed. I am generating a presignedUrl using S3 SDK and uploading a file to a bucket using it. The file actually uploads and the response returns a statusCode of 200 but weirdly there no response body.

I cannot understand if I'm missing some sort of header, or if they're wrong. The `Content-length` on the response headers worries me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Note: I've obscured the values, if they are helpful I can mock them back in

#### General

`Request URL: https://some-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/some/path/file/picture?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAXXXap-southeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=xxx&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Security-Token=xxx&X-Amz-Signature=xxx&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 1.2.3.4:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

#### Request headers

`Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31897
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Host: some-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:5000/some/page
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 xxx`

#### Response headers

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 1 May 2017 01:00:00 GMT
ETag: "xxx"
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2: xxx
x-amz-request-id: xxx`

#### Query String Parameters

`X-Amz-Algorithm: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-Amz-Credential: ASIAXXXap-southeast-2/s3/aws4_request
X-Amz-Date: XXX
X-Amz-Expires: 300
X-Amz-Security-Token: XXX
X-Amz-Signature: XXX
X-Amz-SignedHeaders: host;x-amz-acl
x-amz-acl: public-read`

#### Presigning service (NodeJS, Lambda)

```
... 
const params = {
    Bucket: 'some-bucket',
    Key: 'some/path/file/picture',
    Expires: 60 * 5,
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
    ...
    callback(null, new Response(200, {url});
});
...
```

#### S3 service (TS, Angular)

```
public putObject(presignedUrl: string, file: File): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put<any>(presignedUrl, file);
}
```

#### Component

```
this.s3Service.putObject(presignedUrl, file)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      // it gets here as expected
      // but response is null!
    },
    () => {}
  );
```

Comment: Have you checked out AWS's [troubleshooting docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html) for this error? It looks like the error response should also contain strings that you can test against the strings that you provided.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. I've spent about a week on and off trying to figure this out. This is a weird one, because the image upload is actually successful and response is 200, but empty body...just very strange outcome, nothing in the docs that could explain it.

Comment: One more note- you mentioned you were worried about `Content-length: 0` on the response, but I see in the [s3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) that a sample response for a PUT contains `Content-length: 0`. So that doesn't seem worrisome. What response were you getting before?

Comment: Ah cool, good find. It's always been just a generic `Response` type, as far as I can tell, and I was using the `url` parameter on it.

Comment: It sounds like this is working to me. AWS won't send a 200 response with an error. The error you referenced is listed in their [error response docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) as a `403 SignatureDoesNotMatch` error. It's possible you're somehow looking at another XHR request, or that your browser is caching an earlier response where you weren't authenticated. But if you're receiving a 200 status code and the file uploads, I think you're good to go.

Comment: That's why it's so weird. I'll try and add a screenshot as proof!

Comment: @theholla Ah, I just realised, the reason why I was seeing the error when I double-clicked on the request is because that would then perform a `get` request in the browser on the presigned URL, of course it's going to error. So, will update my post and remove that part.

Comment: Just to understand what exactly is the problem, what do you expect as response? Maybe I am wrong or not understanding your problem, but as you are requesting a `PUT` I believe the response is correct, empty, and the response code `200` says your put date was successfully.

Comment: It used to return a body with a {url: ''} property though...perhaps the API has changed. I *do* have access to what the URL could be in the presigned URL, which I guess I will have to use for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced it using `go` SDK to confirm it is how API itself behaves, not something specific from `nodejs`.

As I can see from my experimentation it is a normal behavior now, it will not return anything from `PUT` request.

OBS: I masked some sensitive values!

**The Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")},
    )

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    req1, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucketversioningenabled"),
        Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
        Body:   strings.NewReader("EXPECTED CONTENTS"),
    })

    presignURL, err := req1.Presign(time.Minute * 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error on presign", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Presign: ", presignURL, err)
    fmt.Println("")

    req2, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", presignURL, strings.NewReader("EXPECTED CONTENTS"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating request", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("NewRequest: ", req2, err)
    fmt.Println("")

    proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://myfiddler.proxy.com:8888")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error on proxy parse", err)
        return
    }

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        Timeout:   time.Duration(5 * time.Second),
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error on request put", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Do: ", resp, err)
}
```

**The execution output:**

Please look the `Content-Length:[0]` on the last line.

```
$ ./s3put 
Presign:  https://bucketversioningenabled.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myKey?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXX%2F20180531%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180531T112707Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token=XXXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=XXXX <nil>

NewRequest:  &{PUT https://bucketversioningenabled.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myKey?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=XXXX%2F20180531%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180531T112707Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token=XXXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=XXXX HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[] {0xc42010d020} 0x5f2040 17 [] false bucketversioningenabled.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>} <nil>

Do:  &{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[X-Amz-Version-Id:[3I4txVUgi4ObULr8EVadA4U3cfvdVwQM] Etag:["952973475e3f4d992fe48578086c1e17"] Content-Length:[0] Server:[AmazonS3] X-Amz-Id-2:[yGUZtjttGKwv0uJxQcG7bIkGRqxhPxKeW71jWIGkmwt73oZY/+r3HWyr2uK07nR8xTDQyzbM3Hw=] X-Amz-Request-Id:[509F1785D0383ADA] Date:[Thu, 31 May 2018 11:27:09 GMT]] 0xc42000c0e0 0 [] false false map[] 0xc42019c400 0xc420199290} <nil>
```

**And below you can see the request and response from Fiddler**

Request:

```
PUT https://bucketversioningenabled.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myKey?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=XXXX%2F20180531%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180531T112707Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token=XXXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=XXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: bucketversioningenabled.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 17
Accept-Encoding: gzip

EXPECTED CONTENTS
```

Response (look the Content-Length):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: yGUZtjttGKwv0uJxQcG7bIkGRqxhPxKeW71jWIGkmwt73oZY/+r3HWyr2uK07nR8xTDQyzbM3Hw=
x-amz-request-id: 509F1785D0383ADA
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 11:27:09 GMT
x-amz-version-id: 3I4txVUgi4ObULr8EVadA4U3cfvdVwQM
ETag: "952973475e3f4d992fe48578086c1e17"
Content-Length: 0
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Looks like you basically just have to use the presigned URL with the parameters chopped off. Not sure what I was doing before. It was probably my mistake. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Did you get a different response with chopped off parameters?

Comment: Sorry I meant in order to store the URL in a database, I just used the presigned with chopped off params.